# Recorrer una lista de forma aleatoria en Python

Tags: python

es posible recorrer en Python una lista de forma aleatoria?
Lo que quiero es recorrer una lista de valores numéricos y que no se repita ninguno pero que no vaya en orden, por ejemplo

```
for i in range(20):
```

pero en vez de i valer 0, 1, 2, 3...
que pueda valer 3, 7, 19, 2...

Comment: La función [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/random.html#random.sample) del modulo [random](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/random.html#module-random) te devuelve una muestra de k elementos ordenados aleatoriamente sin repetir. Puedes usar `k=len(sequencia)` para obtener la secuencia ordenada aleatoriamente.

Comment: O puedes crear una lista que contenga los numeros desordenados y recorrerla en orden: `numeros = list(range(20)); random.shuffle(numeros); for i in numeros: ...`

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes lograr con:

```
resultado = sorted(lista, key=lambda y: random.randint(0, len(lista)))
```

> El valor del parámetro key debe ser una función que tome un solo
> argumento y retorne una clave para usar con fines de clasificación.
> Esta técnica es rápida porque la función key se llama exactamente una
> vez para cada registro de entrada.

El truco está en hacer que `key` retorne un valor aleatorio dentro del rango de indices válidos.

#### Demo

```
import random

lista = list(range(20))
salida = sorted(lista, key=lambda y: random.randint(0, len(lista)))
print(salida)
```

produce:

```
[12, 1, 8, 3, 17, 11, 13, 4, 16, 5, 0, 18, 9, 7, 10, 14, 15, 19, 2, 6]    

Process finished with exit code 0
```